# Using unsigned long in Conditional Breakpoint

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, winapi, windbg

I am not able to have a conditional breakpoint on the variable which is unsigned long. I am using the following expression,

```
bp id4!__Km+0x42 "j (poi(mayvar)>0x1000) '';'gc' "
```

So , the microsoft website says , it treats it as integer, but even though the size and integer and unsigned long is the same for microsoft compiler , I am not able to break it. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I this from a reduced example or from a full blown app? Have you verified this actually works when the var *is* an int?

Comment: `mayvar` is not a typo of `myvar`? poi() is pointer size - is your app 32 or 64 bit? Did you try ?? and @@c++` instead of poi()?

Comment: so , I am debugging in kernel mode ,and the variable is unsigned long

Comment: though j is a shorcut for if else i have observed behavioural differences so i normally stick to the long form and qualify it explicitly with c++ or masm as appropriate  and explicitly terminate with semicolons ie i would try bp MyMod!MySymbol ".if ( @@masm( poi(Mayvar) ) > 0x1000 ) {} .else {gc;} you can always set a hardware ba w1 poi(mayvar) that would show what your variable holds to confirm your syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really think the problem is because of int and unsigned long.

Here are the steps i would follow to disambiguate :

a. First, break into the desired point and check what does poi(mayvar) return. That is execute

> ? poi(mayvar)

Based on whether its a 32 or 64 bit app. It should just return a 32 or 64 bit value.

b. Second, Check if the condition does really work. That is put different values and check both true and false conditions. Using something like

> j poi(mayvar) > 5 '.echo true' ; '.echo false'

c. Third, Now that you are sure that the condition does work. confidently put the conditional break-point!